# null values getting uploaded into hive table from a csv file

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am new to hadoop hive . we are using open source hadoop hive. It is installed on ubuntu a single node cluster. I have 1 million rows of data in a csv file which i moved it from windows to linux. when uploading data into the hive using the foolwing command null values are getting uploaded into the table.

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/home/goldstone/Desktop/RejectStats.csv' 
OVERWRITE INTO TABLE rejstats;
```

I even tried to upload the values by tplacing the file hdfs but stil the same issue.

My table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE rejstats( amount_requested INT , appdate TIMESTAMP , loan_title STRING , dbt_income_ratio FLOAT , city STRING , state STRING , employment_lenght STRING)
ROW FORMAT
DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

I am attaching the screen shot of the null values returned.

please anyone could help me with this issue. Thank You.

Regards,
Divya.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are trying to input a comma separated file in a table where you are using `FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'` i.e tab. Try the following:

```
CREATE TABLE rejstats (amount_requested INT , appdate TIMESTAMP , 
loan_title STRING , dbt_income_ratio FLOAT , city STRING , 
state STRING , employment_lenght STRING) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS 
TERMINATED BY ',' STORED AS TEXTFILE;

LOAD DATA INPATH '/home/goldstone/Desktop/RejectStats.csv' 
OVERWRITE INTO TABLE rejstats;
```

Comment: Is Timestamp data type supported in hive? because i am facing an error during retrieving data from a hive table containing timestamp datatype.

Comment: hive does support timestamps, but the default format (when reading from a string via csv) is `YYYY-MM-dd HH:MM:SS.000`